# an error occurred while building a Java Card project in Eclipse javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: eclipse, javacard

When I want to build a sample Java Card project in Eclipse I got the following error:
"Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Oracle Java Card SDK Builder' on project 'HelloWorld'.
javax/xml/bind/JAXBException"

I am using:
Eclipse Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
JRE7
JDK1.7.0_80
Java Card Development Kit 3.0.5u4

I have added jre7 and jdk1.7.0_80 in Eclipse Preferences->Java->Installed JREs
but the result is the same

I have also added jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar manually to the Referenced Libraries (Java Build Path-> Libraries)
but the result is the same

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Which version of Java are you using to run *Eclipse*?

Comment: Could you please explain how you are trying to build applet and send here complete log?